# Sony SmartWatch - Keep accelerometer data coming for a few hours

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to write a control extension that would gather accelerometer data from Sony SW2 continuously for ~8 hours. I have a first version of that extension, but based on user reports, it always runs for ~1 hour and then stops sending data. I do not have any SmartWatch for testing and this problem cannot be simulated on emulator.

My first question would be - it is possible at all to achieve such a behaviour? If so, would it ruin SW2 battery?

In case this can be done technically, is there any tip what should be done? I use the SCREEN_STATE_OFF mode as suggested in documentation, but apparently that is not enough.

Comment: Sounds like you need the real hardware.

Comment: In case the concept is feasible, that would be fine. If not, it would be just a waste of money as I have some other (as well for development) and won't likely ever use these. Anyway, I'd think purpose of emulator is to allow development without actual device, so maybe the real thing to be fixed is the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any limitations in the length of time you can capture accelerometer data, however 8 hours is a pretty long time so I would expect it to drain the battery significantly even if you were to turn the screen off.

With the use case you described I don't think there would be any way to accurately emulate the battery drain of a SW2 based on sensor usage.  Some things you just have to have to real hardware for.  The emulator can never 100% replicate a HW device.

Comment: I understand battery drain cannot be simulated, my concern about simulating was about a sudden stopping of tracking.